# Have you seen this Sci Fi movie\show before? (Reptilians)

Tags: story-identification, aliens

**Does anybody know from what show\movie this picture is from? , It looks like some Sci fi show in the 80s-90s I am not sure and also if anybody knows the name of this actress it would be very helpful.**

[image]

Comment: Ok cool thanks guys

Comment: I think she was in some kind of Sheena-of-the-jungle/Land-of-the-Lost type show. I vaguely remember her just because she was way too clean and pretty to play a jungle-girl. A short-lived show from the WB network, IIRC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep - The show was "The Lost World", 1999-2002 (lasted longer than I thought)

[image]

The actress is [Jennifer O'Dell](http://www.tvrage.com/person/id-18647/Jennifer+O%27Dell), AKA Jennifer O'Dell Scarlett

The episode in question seems to be "The Games".

Comment: http://karavansara.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/the-pulp-lost-world/ - To wit, I believe the lizardman is Tribune, their leader.

Comment: Wow thanks dude your awesome I've been looking for this show forever I knew it was familiar , anyway thanks again

Comment: @stargazer: Thanks! My pleasure. Please remember to check the "Answered" mark!

Comment: Minor correction: the actress is [Jennifer O'Dell](http://www.jenodell.com/). Lara Cox plays a different character, not the Jungle Girl.

Comment: @Andres F.: Thanks! Correction made.